# How to get data from 2D tensor?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I would like to get the data from a 2D tensor with [tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/). I tried to use the `data()` method like this:

```
const X = tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 3]]);
X.data().then(X => console.log(X)};
```

But the result is a flatten 1D array:

```
Float32Array(8) [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3]
```

Is there a way to keep the shape of the array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use arraySync method on the tensor object. It returns the array as the same shape it was before **synchronously**.

```js
const X = tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 3]]); 
console.log(X.arraySync())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.7/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in the Tensor is always stored flattened as types 1 dimensional array, for speed.

The example you gave will not work, because 2nd parameter to `tensor2d` is `shape`. To make it work you either need to wrap it another array:

```
const x = tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 3]]); //shape inferred as [2, 4]
```

or you could explicitly provide shape:

```
const x = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3], [2, 4]); // shape explicitly passed
```

as you suggested though, when you inspect data you will always get 1 dimensional array, regardless of original shape

```
await x.data() // Float32Array(8) [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3]
x.shape // [2, 4]
```

if however you `print()` your tensor, shape is taken into account and it will appear as

```
Tensor
    [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [2, 2, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was a typo: I actually used `tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 3]]);`. But how can I get only one column of the tensor since `x.data()` gives a flat Float32Array?

Comment: guessing you would need to inspect `.shape` `[x,y]` and then only take `y` elements from your array, if you want second column then its `skip y, take y` (not actual JS code)

Comment: Yes I end up using the shape of the tensor to slice the array returned by `data()`. Just wondering if there is a way to keep the shape (like with an array of array returned by `tensor2d.data()`).

Comment: I like await data() since you usually are in an async function anyways to load the model

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function to show the 2D tensor in a webpage

```
async function myTensorTable(myDiv, myOutTensor, myCols, myTitle){   

 document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML += myTitle + '<br>'
 const myOutput = await myOutTensor.data()
 myTemp = '<table border=3><tr>'
   for (myCount = 0;    myCount <= myOutTensor.size - 1;   myCount++){   
     myTemp += '<td>'+ myOutput[myCount] + '</td>'
     if (myCount % myCols == myCols-1){
         myTemp += '</tr><tr>'
     }
   }   
   myTemp += '</tr></table>'
   document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML += myTemp + '<br>'
}
```

examples of usage at

https://hpssjellis.github.io/beginner-tensorflowjs-examples-in-javascript/beginner-examples/tfjs02-basics.html

Comment: I don't think OP was asking to build a HTML table, the question was to keep the shape of tensor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code actually helped me with my separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000400/tensorflow-js-getting-the-result-into-a-variable/50000585#50000585