# How to get the value of the element i, j of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a 2d tensor and I would like to get the value of the element of index i,j value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways one can retrieve the value of the element [i,j] of a tensor2d

Consider the following:

Using [slice](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#slice) to retrieve directly the tensor2d starting at the coordinate [i, j] that has the size [1, 1]

```
h.slice([i, j], 1).as1D().print()
```

Get the row i as a tensor2d with [gather](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#gather) and then the element j with [slice](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#slice)

```
h.gather(tf.tensor1d([i], 'int32')).slice([0, j], [1, 1]).as1D().print()
```

Using [stack](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#stack) to retrieve the row i as tensor1d and [slice](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#slice) to retrieve the desired element

```
h.unstack()[i].slice([j], [1]).print()
```

```js
const h = tf.tensor2d([45, 48, 45, 54, 5, 7, 8, 10, 54], [3, 3]);
// get the element of index [1, 2]
h.print()
h.gather(tf.tensor1d([1], 'int32')).slice([0, 2], [1, 1]).as1D().print()
h.slice([1, 2], 1).as1D().print()
h.unstack()[1].slice([2], [1]).print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

If the goal is to get the element [i, j] in order to use it in other tensor computation like divide/multiply the matrix by the element, you will need to convert the element to a scalar.

```
h.slice([i, j], 1).as1D().asScalar()
```

If you want to return that value to a javascript variable (of type number), then you will need [dataSync()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) or [data()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tf.Tensor.data) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000400/getting-the-result-into-a-variable/51847302#51847302)

```js
h.slice([i, j], 1).as1D().dataSync()[0]
// or
const data = await h.slice([i, j], 1).as1D().data()
```

```js
const h = tf.tensor2d([45, 48, 45, 54, 5, 7, 8, 10, 54], [3, 3]);
// get the element of index [1, 2]
h.print()
// sync method
const val = h.unstack()[1].slice([2], [1]).dataSync()
console.log(val[0]);
// async method
(async () => {
  const val = await h.slice([1, 2], 1).as1D().data()
  console.log(val[0])
})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.12.4/tf.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.dataSync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) or if you can wait for it [`.data()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tf.Tensor.data) to retrieve an 1d array containing all values of a tensor.

Now we only have to calculate an 1d-index from the 2d-coordinates using the formula:

> index = rowlength * rownumber + columnnumber

The following code shows how to use each version.

*Notice the `async` and `await` in the asynchronous method: `async` makes the function async, so we can use `await` to wait for another promise to resolve (`.data()` retuns a promise). Because an async function returns a promise we have to wait for it before logging it using `.then()`*

```js
function getValSync(t, i, j) {
  const data = t.dataSync();
  return data[t.shape[0] * j + i]; //Or *i+j, depending on what the dimension order is
}

async function getValAsync(t, i, j) {
  const data = await t.data();
  return data[t.shape[0] * j + i];
}

const t2d = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);

t2d.print();

console.log("1,0:", getValSync(t2d, 1, 0));
console.log("1,1:", getValSync(t2d, 1, 1));

getValAsync(t2d, 0, 0).then(v => console.log("0,0:", v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0">
</script>
```