# Tensorflow.js `tensor2d` to numerical values while preserving the shape

Tags: typescript, tensorflow, angular7, tensorflow.js

Using `tensorflowjs` inside an Angular7 project, I am encountering trouble in accessing the numerical values of a `tensor2d` object.

Indeed:

```
let tensor2d = tf.tensor2d( [[1,2],[3,4]])
let tensor2d_array = tensor2d.dataSync()
```

will give an `Array` object of shape `(4,)` instead of `(2,2,)` as I wish.

How can I preserve the shape and get an array of my tensor. (Reshaping by hand is not practical in all cases, as I do not have access to a js matrix library in this project..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dataSync](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) and [data](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.data) returns a flatten [typedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). It means that `tensor2d_array` will be of shape [4].

Instead of getting the data with the same shape as the tensor, maybe it will be practical to get only the index value that you want to retrieve. Having said that, if for a certain reason, you want to get the data array first before getting the value at the index `[i, j]`, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848367/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-element-i-j-of-a-tensor/51848542#51848542) shows how you can retrieve element `[i, j]` of the data got using either `data` or `dataSync`

**Update**

Since the `version 15`, it is possible to get an array with the same shape as the tensor using [tensor.array()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.array) or [tensor.arraySync()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.arraySync())

Comment: So the shape preserving solution, in this use case, is running a double for loop and some `get` method to populate a new array? I see a performance bottleneck there.

Comment: Just did, accepted. Many thanks, this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Note: arraySync preserves the shape although console.log() might make it seem like it does not: 
'Tensor  [[0, 0], [0, 5], [1, 0], 1, 4], [1, 5]]` printed out after arraySync simply becomes `0,0,0,5,1,0,1,4,1,5` although in fact the shape is preserved.