# How to get an element from a specific index, where index is a scalar tensor with TensorFlow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've recently finished a course where we've used an older version of TensorFlow.js, and there were a useful method on tensors (not just buffers): `.get()`. Since it has been removed, I have to use a different solution to create my simplified learning rate optimisation, where I compare the previous cost to the new cost, if the previous is bigger, increase the learning rate, otherwise decrease it. Cost is always a scalar tensor, I stack the previous one with the new cost, get the index of the bigger one with `.argMax()`, and get the item from my "constant" tensor which just stores two values, how much to multiply the learning rate with, by the index -the result of `.argMax()`.

An example would be:

```
let learningRate = tf.tensor(1);

const prevCost = tf.tensor(1);
const nextCost = tf.tensor(2);

const modifiers = tf.tensor([1.05, 0.5]);

const bigger = tf.stack([prevCost, nextCost]).argMax(); // 1

const modifier = modifiers.get(// if it would still exist
  bigger
); // 0.5

learningRate = learningRate.mul(modifier); // 1 * 0.5 = 0.5
```

But unfortunately `.get()` doesn't exist anymore, however, there should be a method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.slice` can be used as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848367/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-element-i-j-of-a-tensor/51848542#51848542)

```
tensor.slice([...cordinates], 1)
```

Comment: `.slice()` only accepts numbers, but doesn't accept a scalar tensor. As seen in the example `bigger`, the index what I want to get the correct `modifier` from `modifiers` is a scalar tensor.

Comment: `get` previously does not accept tensor nor scalar either. It only accepts numbers

Comment: True, but with `get` I can easily get a number from a tensor, and transfer that to another. Now because `get` doesn't exist anymore on tensors, I have to work just with tensors, however, your solution definitely can get an element back from a tensor, but it returns a tensor, by passing in a number. So it doesn't solve the problem in the example in the description.

Comment: Whatever you are doing with `get` you can do it by slicing at a coordinates. Maybe you also need to use `dataSync` to get the number out of the tensor. All of these is discussed in the link I gave in the answer