# Access to single values of tensor2d in TensorFlow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to access the elements of the second row of the 2d matrix using TensorFlow.js package. Here below I access to the first and second element of the first row of the matrix by using `[0]` and `[1]`, but honestly I would expect to access those element like `[0][0]` for get **1** and `[1][1]` for get **4**.

```
const t1 = tf.tensor2d([
                         [1,2],
                         [3,4]
                         ]);

    const tensorData = t1.dataSync();
    console.log("data[0] is " + tensorData[0]); // I get 1
    console.log("data[1] is " + tensorData[1]); // I get 2
    console.log("data[0][0] is " + tensorData[0][0]); // I get undefined, but I would expect to get 1
```

Can someone explain me why? And how could I can access to the single elements of the second row of the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the tensor value by coordinate, there is the `get` method. Here is an example

```
const a=tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2])
b=a.get(0,0)
console.log(b)
```

You can also have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848367/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-element-i-j-of-a-tensor/51848542#51848542)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use `Tensor.get`, this will actually be deprecated when we do a major version update.

You should use:

```
const buffer = tensor.buffer();
const value = buffer.get(i, j, k);
```

If you want to index into multiple values, please store the `TensorBuffer` as an object. This will keep all values on the CPU and allow you to index into them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Sintax tensorData[0][0] is correct, but looks like your tensorData var is equal to  [1, 2, 3, 4] without second row at all.

Just check what tensorData exactly contains before accessing.

Comment: This is the ouput of print for **t1**: Tensor
    [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]] While if I try to print tensorData I got a console log error about that print command is not a function.

Comment: tensorData is just array. you can use  `console.log(tensorData);` to see what it contains

Comment: `Float32Array(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]`...hmmm seems that with `dataSync()` I got only **1d array**.

Comment: look this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646291/get-data-from-2d-tensor-with-tensorflow-js about tensor2d init